# Drag & Drop using Jquery

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I understand how to run a basic drag and drop, there are numerous tutorials on the web. However, what i need to achieve is to drag an element, for example an item from a list. But when i drop this element into a target DIV, i need other things dropped which are attributes of the dragged element.

For example i drag the name of an exercise from DIV1 but when i drop it into DIV2 i drop an image, description, sets and reps of the exercise into their respective divs which are siblingndivs of the parent droppable DIV2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery UI to accomplish this task.

jQuery UI code (Javascript):

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
drop: function( event, ui ) {
$( this )
.addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
.find( "p" )
.html( "Dropped!" );
}
});
});
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
<p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>
<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
<p>Drop here</p>
</div>
```

You can also refer [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#default).